Two questions about the expansion of the universe and matter?
I have a couple of questions about the consequences that the expansion of the universe (being an accelerated expansion or a linear one) would have on matter and structures in the universe
1. Neutrinos:
Neutrinos are the most abundant particle in the universe and they are present everywhere in space. However, as they have a really small mass and do not interact with almost anything they are very difficult to detect. Due to their extremely high velocities (close to the speed of light) and their low mass, they are not gravitationally bound to anything and free-roam through the universe (at most, they form overdensities around high gravitational wells like superclusters of galaxies, but not linked to them).
One would then think that, as they are not bound to anything, they will be more and more dispersed by the expansion of the universe.
But if they are so abundant, shouldn't there be a very weak but non-zero gravitational interaction betweem them, and because of that, they will never get dispersed by the expansion of the universe (as it does not act upon bound particles)? And if that would be true, since neutrinos will lose velocity with time as their momentum gets redshifted by the expansion, once they have slowed down enough, shouldn't they form gravitationally bound neutrino clusters?
2. Black holes:
Black holes will evaporate with time due to Hawking radiation, losing mass in the process.
Now, they are increasing their mass (at least the biggest ones, which would emit extremely low energetic Hawking radiation) as they absorb CMB photons.
When the CMB radiation will get redshifted in the future, then no black hole would be able to absorb it (as the CMB temperature would be colder than the horizon temperature). However, they will still be able to absorb matter (like protons, electrons, positrons, neutrinos...).
Here we have 2 basic options for an eternally expanding universe, that is, one that does not end up in a big crunch (a topologically closed universe):
a) For a universe that keeps expanding with acceleration (one that has a truly constant cosmological constant) there would be a cosmological horizon where radiation would be emitted (similarly to a black hole horizon). Then, for the most massive black holes in the universe, there could be a situation in which the radiation they lose by Hawking radiation is compensated by the radiation impregnating the universe coming from the cosmological horizon, so they reach an equilibrium and never really evaporate
b) For a universe that keeps expanding linearly (one that doesn't have a cosmological constant but keeps expanding because it's globally flat or open) there wouldn't be a cosmological horizon, but because of this, the local patch of the universe wouldn't be isolated from the rest of it, and therefore would allow matter and radiation from "outside" to get in. Then, if it's truly spatially flat, there should be an unlimited amount of particles (like neutrinos) and radiation that black holes could absorb (a similar idea: https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.217.4560.593). However, I'm not sure what would happen in an open geometry for such linearly expanding universe...
Then, in either case, shouldn't black holes avoid evaporation (at least some of them)?

Gravity acts on more than just mass you know, even if neutrinos were massless they would still feel gravitational effects since they would have energy. Much like how light is bent in gravitational potential wells.

@Triatticus yes but they wouldn't be gravitationally bound to the potential

@vengaq massless objects can indeed be bound to a gravitational potential, provided the metric allows for closed lightlike geodesics that are sufficiently stable against perturbations. A Schwarzschild black hole spacetime contains such geodesics at $r=3GM/c^2$, known as the photon sphere.

@paulina indeed in that case. But in the case of neutrinos bound to superclusters I'm afraid it doesn't happen or at least is not completely clear that they do

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/355676

1. The self-gravitation of the CνB is nonzero, but it's smaller than that of the CMB, and both are far below the threshold to form bound structures of neutrinos/photons. Even the much larger gravitational effect of baryonic matter on the neutrinos/photons isn't enough.
2a. If $Λ>0$, the cosmological horizon has a positive temperature, but it is lower than that of any black hole that fits inside, so the black hole will eventually evaporate. No structure can be larger than the horizon, not even a black hole.
2b. If $Λ=0$, the background temperature will drop toward absolute zero as the universe expands, eventually dropping below the temperature of any black hole. Even if unboundedly many massive particles arrive from unboundedly far away over unbounded amounts of time, they will arrive slowly enough that the Hawking evaporation will eventually dominate. The paper you linked suggests that it may be possible to avoid that locally by actively clumping matter, which may be true, as I said in my answer to an earlier question of yours about the same paper. If $Λ<0$, I think that there are no eternally expanding solutions to the Friedmann equations, unless there is also quintessence that makes $Λ$ effectively nonnegative.

How about putting a black hole in the presence of AdS to prevent it from evaporating? @benrg

Something like this: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269322000302 @benrg

@vengaq That paper is right - in AdS space the radiation will tend to gravitate back into the hole. This makes me realize that I don't know much about cosmology or black hole evaporation when $Λ<0$. I edited the answer slightly.
